# An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream

Tags: java, google-chrome, audio-streaming, dropwizard

I am building a music streaming app using dropwizard, but behaviors at safari and chrome is totally different. At safari it play with complete time but chrome it break in between.
I get following error on server side.

```
ERROR [2016-07-06 04:01:44,258] org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
! java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
! at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
! at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
! at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:170) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! ... 10 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:364) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:111) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:640) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:611) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:549) ~[jetty-io-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread.run(NonBlockingThread.java:52) ~[jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I further debug it for chrome browser.
From chrome browser I get two request to get audio data and server side it provides complete data for two request. 
But surprisingly, in middle chrome browser request another chunk of data. Since Byte buffer position already reached buffer limit so it unable to provide any further data.
I saw it was due to End of File was null. I have kept data as blob in cassandra and using LRU cache to serve mine client to avoid large memory footprint. 
I like to understand behavior difference between safari and chrome and How can I solve it for chrome. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm getting the same exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have had this exception when I accidentally passed a null Response at the end of a call. You can verify this in the'caused by' section following the first exception:

Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null